# How to phrase a sentence based on particular community

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, american-english, terminology

Hi Friends i am new to this group.I have a doubt like how to phrase a sentence based on community.

Like i have different departments is there like sales,support,orders etc.

For ex:

How to phrase a sentence like

> **Demo cannot be less than particular date.**

Means like Demo happen cannot be less can demo scheduled date

It sounds very annoying because should we use greater than when comparing two dates.How to phrase this sentence

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. This site is for Linguists, Etymologists and Serious English Enthusiasts. Please fix all your typos and explain why it sounds annoying. How do you want us to rephrase the sentence? What is Demo? Demonstration?

Comment: Thanks @Rathony i updated my question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question, but here's how I would rephrase that sentence:

1. The demo cannot be scheduled before that particular date.
2. The demo must be held after that particular date.

In formal writing, I would use "Demonstration" in place of "Demo."

(I assume you are referring to product demonstrations.)

Comment: please have a look on my question once again.

Comment: Use <before>, <after> or <on>  when talking about dates, instead of <greater than> and <less than>.
Other words you can use are <earlier than> and <later than>.